# Print all void subdirectories, using a shell

Tags: bash, shell, directory, directory-structure

I'd like to get a list of all void descendant directories of a directory. I realized I wasn't able to do this easily with any shell. How would you do it ?

Yet, I can do it much more easily with python. For instance:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from os import walk, listdir
for path,_,_ in walk("."):
     if listdir(path)==[]:
         print(path)
```

Comment: I mean descendant directories. I admit it wasn't clear.

Comment: From the parent directory you can use `find . -type d`

Comment: What should I pipe it to then ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `find` command:

```
find . -type d -empty
```